# @products.each do returns NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, nomethoderror

I have a ProductsController and a products view. In the controller, I fetch the products via the Shopify API and display the products in the view which works perfectly fine. However, I want to call a method called `create_entries` from the view. This works if `create_entries` contains something like `puts @products` BUT I cannot loop through the products.

controller:

```
class ProductsController < AuthenticatedController
  def index
    @products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: { limit: 10 })
  end

  def create_entries
    @products.each do |p|
      puts 'hi'
    end
  end

  helper_method :create_entries
end
```

How I call the method from the view:

```
<%= link_to "Create entries", create_entries, class: "link" %>
```

This gives me the error `NoMethodError in Products#index` followed by a long error message which starts like this:

```
undefined method `shopify_api_product_shopify_api_product_shopify_api_product_shopify_api_product_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000001129b6050>:0x00000001129a57c8 @_routes=nil, @_config={}, @lookup_context=#<ActionView::LookupContext:0x0000000117e87048 @details_key=#<Object:0x0000000112c9a370>, @digest_cache=nil, @cache=true, @prefixes=["products", "authenticated", "application"], @details={:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :slim]}, @view_paths=#<ActionView::PathSet:0x0000000117e86d28 @paths=[#<ActionView::OptimizedFileSystemResolver:0x0000000112834240 @pattern=":prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:formats,}{+:variants,}{.:handlers,}", @unbound_templates=#<Concurrent::Map:0x0000000112834218 entries=5 default_proc=nil>, @cache=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache:0x24c70 keys=1 queries=0>,
```

But it only happens when I use `.each do`. The following works:

```
  def create_entries
    puts @products[0].title
    puts @products[1].title
    puts @products[2].title
  end
```

This displays the titles of the first three products. I do not understand how this works, but iterating with each do doesn't? Can someone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the `<%= link_to` expects a route for the second argument. In other words: `create_entries_products_path`. Secondly, calling a helper method that loops through the products in a link is not the way to create multiple links. Instead you should do an each block that wraps the link helper. (See below)

I would recommend changing your code in the following ways:

1. If you are to continue using your helper method, move your `create_entries` helper to a helper file since the controller is not the best place for it. Place it in here: app/helpers/products_helper.rb. I would *actually* recommend using the instance variable of `@products`. Looping through this collection should allow you to do the same thing.
2. Wrap your link with an `each` and loop through your `@products`:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
   <%= link_to product.name, product_path(product), class: 'link' %>
<% end %>
```